# limit scope of session in cakephp

Tags: session, cakephp

Using CakePHP 2.  I have the directory structure:

```
/var/www/basesite
            /appdev
                /app (and all other cake dirs)
            /appqa
                /app
            /appstage
                /app
```

So I have three different sites all with the same baseurl but different subdirectories, all of which contain substantially the same code.  Everything works, all the apps load and operate successfully.

The problem is, if a user logs in on dev, and then views QA, they are logged in.  And if they then log out on QA and return to dev, they are logged out on dev also.

**The Question:**

How and where can I set the session scope to ensure it is limited to the appropriate sub-path for each instance of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set it via the cookie_path in your /app/Config/core.php using session.ini.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'ini' => array(
        'session.cookie_path' => '/app/dir'
    )
));
```

Comment: thanks much.  I still haven't quite figured my way around the book.  I looked in core libraries->components->session, but didn't realize there was another place to find session documentation.

Comment: Powerful framework and the core items are well documented, but as you said some of the stuff is sprinkled throughout. Then sometimes, I just end up reading source. ;)

Comment: @Robert, i'm having the same urgent issue but i can't seem to resolve it even with the above answer or other answers on SO. If you don't mind me getting in contact with you personally, I'd very much appreciate it.